The integral of $\int_0^1 x^a(1+x)^b(1-x)^c e^{-dx^2} dx$
As the title mentioned, I want to get a closed-form result of
$\int_0^1 x^a(1+x)^b(1-x)^c e^{-dx^2} dx,$
where $d>0$, $a,b,c$ may be very large numbers.
A related integral is
$\int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b e^{cx} dx = B(a+1,b+1){_1F_1}(a+1;a+b+2;c),$
where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function, ${_1F_1}(\cdot;\cdot;\cdot)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function.
I have tried my best but the part of $(1+x)^b$ is really annoying. If a exact result is difficult, any tight upper bound is also welcomed.

If $b=c$ there is a solution

Definitely, in this case we have $(1 - x^2)$ which not only solves the problem of $(1+x)$ but also solve the exponent by letting $p=x^2$. Unfortunately, in my problem $b \neq c$.

To find the asymptotics we need some relations between $a, ,b,,c$. For example, $c\ll b$

@Svyatoslav Hi, love to see you again. In my exact problem, $|c| \ll |b|$ is exactly the case, is there any possible bound if this condition is satisfied? BTW, I have worked out an upper bound using Holder's inequality as $[\int_0^1 x^{2a}（1-x^2）^{2c}e^{-2dx^2}dx \int_0^1 (1+x)^{2b-2c}dx]^{0.5}$, this bound can be tight if the value of the parameters are suitable for Holder's, i.e., makes the two integrals close to linear to each other.
